# Tratativa para salvar sinal de + no BD através de um formulário de cadastro

Tags: php, javascript, formulário, input

Tenho um formulário de cadastro de marca de pneus, em um dos campos input onde informo o modelo do pneus, preciso passar o sinal de + exemplo(ecoplus+). Pego os valores dos campos através de uma função JavaScript, e passo para o php realizar a inserção desses dados no BD,  porém esta salvando apenas a escrita(ecoplus)e o sinal de + não salva na tabela do BD. Preciso criar uma tratativa que permita salvar a descrição e o sinal de +.

**Função JavaScript**

```
 function executafuncao(id) {
  if (id == "save") {
    var cdmodelo = document.getElementById('cd_modelo').value;
    var nome = document.getElementById('txtnome').value;
    var cdmarca = document.getElementById('marca').value;
    var status = document.getElementById('ativo').value;

    if (nome != '') {
      nome = nome.replace("'", "");
    }

    if (nome == "") {
      alert('Informe a descri\u00e7\u00e3o do modelo!');
      document.getElementById('txtnome').focus();
    } else if (cdmarca == 0) {
      alert('Selecione a marca!');
      document.getElementById('marca').focus();
    } else {
      if (cdmodelo == '') {
        Tipo = "I"
      } else {
        Tipo = "A";
      }

      window.open('cadastros/modelopneu/acao.php?Tipo=' + Tipo + '&codigo=' + cdmodelo + '&nome=' + nome + '&cdmarca=' + cdmarca + '&status=' + status, "acao");
    }
  }
} 
//Codigo php que insere no BD

$insert = "INSERT INTO pneu_modelos (ds_modelo, cd_marca, cd_usercadastro) 
            VALUES (UPPER('".$nome."'), ".$cdmarca.", ".$_SESSION["CD_USUARIO"].") 
            RETURNING cd_modelo";
        
        $rss_insert = pg_query($conexao, $insert);
        
        while ($linha = pg_fetch_row($rss_insert)) { $nr_modelo = $linha[0]; }
        
        if($nr_modelo!=''){
            echo "<script language='JavaScript'>
              alert('Modelo cadastrado com sucesso!');
              window.parent.executafuncao('new');
              window.parent.consultar(0);
            </script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script language='JavaScript'>alert('Problemas ao gravar!');</script>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja essa pergunta [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/137387).

Answer (score 1):

Para passar parâmetros via javascript você precisa usar: `encodeURIComponent(str)`, veja no caso do seu exemplo seria:

**ES6:**

```
`cadastros/modelopneu/acao.php?Tipo=${encodeURIComponent(Tipo)}&codigo=${encodeURIComponent(cdmodelo)}&nome=${  encodeURIComponent(nome)}&cdmarca=${encodeURIComponent(cdmarca)}&status=${encodeURIComponent(status)}`
```

**ES5:**

```
'cadastros/modelopneu/acao.php?Tipo='+encodeURIComponent(Tipo)+'&codigo='+encodeURIComponent(cdmodelo)+'&nome=' + encodeURIComponent(nome) + '&cdmarca='+encodeURIComponent(cdmarca)+'&status='+ encodeURIComponent(status);
```